# node-mysql query in model object constructor

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm begginer in javascript. I try to write a model for use with Express and node-mysql. It define class Place.
When i create an object instance: `var p = new Place(10);` it should initialize object and fill it variables. But initialization data store in db, and query is async, 
so i think that object was created first and i don't know what happens with data returned from database and how to right initialize object instance variables.

```
var db = app.db; // app is set as GLOBAL

// constructor
var Place = function(place_id) {
    this.getPlaceById.call(place_id, function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;

        this.id = result.id;
        this.title = result.title;
        this.city = result.city;
        this.address = result.address;
    });
}

Place.prototype.getPlaceById = function (place_id, callback) {
    db.query(
        'call getPlaceById(?);', /*  call stored procedure  */
        [ place_id ],
        function(err, results, fields) {
            if(err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                callback(null, results[0][0]);
            }
        }
    );
}

module.exports = Place;
```

As result i have got a strange error:

```
function(place_id) {
...
} has no method 'replace'
    at Object.SqlString.escape (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/SqlString.js:40:13)
    at .../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/SqlString.js:72:22
    at String.replace (native)
```

If i leave empty constructor and just call:

```
p.getPlaceById(10, function(err,r) {
    console.log(r)
});
```

It works without errors and return correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

```
var Place = function(place_id, fn) {
    var self = this;

    Place.prototype.getPlaceById.call(this, place_id, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            fn.call(self, err)
        }
        else {
            self.id = result.id;
            self.title = result.title;
            self.city = result.city;
            self.address = result.address;

            fn.call(self);
        }
    });
}
```

And create an object instance so:

```
var p = new Place(place_id,function(err,result){
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    else
        console.log(p);
});
```